# Importing public key from keyserver causes my secret key to lose its signing capability

Tags: gnupg

I am somewhat puzzled by the behavior I see with GnuPG 2.0.30.

For some reason I noticed recently that my key had lost its ability to sign documents. So I investigated a bit and sure enough I found this:

```
pub  4096R/0xDEADBEEF0000F00D  created: 2000-01-01  expires: never       usage: C
                               trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/0xFEEDFEEDFEEDF00D  created: 2000-01-01  expires: never       usage: E
```

As you can see neither the primary nor the subkey have the `S` usage enabled.

Alright, so I decided to delete my key pair and re-import it from an earlier backup which I knew was good.

This worked fine and sure enough I now saw an `SC` as usage for the primary key.

```
pub  4096R/0xDEADBEEF0000F00D  created: 2000-01-01  expires: never       usage: SC
                               trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/0xFEEDFEEDFEEDF00D  created: 2000-01-01  expires: never       usage: E
```

However, any time I update the public key from a key server (I am using `eu.pool.sks-keyservers.net`), I end up getting the `S` usage stripped from my primary key.

So here's the question: how can I re-enable the `S` (signing) usage for a primary key.

And bonus points to those able to point out why updating the public key affects the capabilities of my secret key like that.

Answer (score 3):

> And bonus points to those able to point out why updating the public key affects the capabilities of my secret key like that.

The secret key does not know anything about capabilities. Those are defined in a special signature storing configuration on your key, while the public/private key pair is technically capable of doing both signatures and encryption. This is only generally valid for the widely-spread RSA keys, though: both DSA and ElGamal, as well as most newer ellyptic-curve cryptography algorithms have separate keys for the different operations.

But how can a key "lose" it's already-set signing capability just because you fetched an update from the key server network? OpenPGP messages as well as key files are constructed from smaller entities, OpenPGP packets. A key for example consists of packets defining the actual keys (the numbers the key is defined by), together with user IDs, certifications and already mentioned special configuration signatures. When you update a key, those individual packets are merged together. In case of conflicts (for example, different configuration signatures), the newest one wins.

What I suspect in your case is that you have a configuration packet with *newer* timestamp on the key server network, while there is an older on your computer. This must have been generated by somebody having access to your private key, so most likely (and hopefully) it must have been you. You can try to verify my assumption by running `gpg --export <key-id> | gpg --list-packets` both before and after fetching the updates, and search for lines containing the definition of `key flags`. These are a bitfield as defined by [OpenPGP, RFC 4880, 5.2.3.21.  Key Flags](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.3.21). For example, my own key has a key flag `3` (binary `11`), which means it has certification capability (binary `01`) and signatures (binary `10`).

```
0x01 - This key may be used to certify other keys.
0x02 - This key may be used to sign data.
0x04 - This key may be used to encrypt communications.
[snip]
```

You will observe one such packet for each user ID you have.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for an answer from someone like you. I read several other answers from you while investigating, including one about migrating a primary key into as subkey into a new primary key.